# Why is this Calendar object's YEAR set to a strange value?

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, max

I am writing an app about calendars. Now I am trying to be familiar with the `Calendar` class.

I wrote some code to get the `DAY_OF_WEEK` of the date `1st Jan, Integer.MAX_VALUE`. I thought it was going to throw an exception or something. But it didn't! It outputs Thursday! Here is the code:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, Integer.MAX_VALUE);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
c.set(Calendar.DATE, 1);
System.out.println (getReadableDayOfWeek(c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)));
```

Note: The method `getReadableDayOfWeek` just does what it says.

Then, when I look at the docs, I found out that there is a method called `getMaximum`. So there really *is* a max! So I added some `println` to see what the actual max is:

```
System.out.println ("Maximum Year: " + c.getMaximum(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println ("Maximum Integer: " + Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

The output is:

```
Maximum Year:    292278994
Maximum Integer: 2147483647
```

Now I know that the max is way less than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`. I wonder what *real* value did I set the `YEAR` to:

```
System.out.println ("Actual Year in Calendar object:  " + c.get (Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println ("Maximum Year:                    " + c.getMaximum(Calendar.YEAR));
System.out.println ("Maximum Integer:                 " + Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

I guess it would output the same number as `c.getMaximum(Calendar.YEAR)`, but it didn't!

Output:

```
Actual Year in Calendar object:  190728635
Maximum Year:                    292278994
Maximum Integer:                 2147483647
```

I am super confused. Why does it have this result? Can you get the day of week after the year 292278994?

Comment: On an unrelated note, now that we have Java 8 I suggest that abandon this horrible and bug ridden API and switch to [JSR 310](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/jf14-date-time-2125367.html).

Comment: I don't think you can use Java 8 to write an android app, can you? @BoristheSpider

Comment: If you can't use Java 8, use Joda, which was the inspiration, or ThreeTen.

Comment: You could look at the [sources](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java#GregorianCalendar.getMaximum%28int%29) (openjdk6) (this [line](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/GregorianCalendar.java#448) explains the 292278994)

Comment: @chrylis I tried JodaTime but I soon found out that the maximum year is still the same number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is an example of an integer overflow case in java. Overflows do not throw exceptions in java.

See this paper: http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-overflow-and-underflow/

Because Integer.MAX_VALUE is greater than c.getMaximum(Calendar.YEAR)), you will get overflow.